# Using styled-components to add styled different components in a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, styled-components

I have a components that prints a grid like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Foo from './Foo';
import Bar from './Bar';

import styled from 'styled-components';

const Item = styled.div`
    border-radius: 50%;
`;

const MyComponent = ({width, height}) => {
    const cellCount = width * height;
    const activeCells = [3, 33, 88, 14, 100, 111];

    return (
        <div>
            {[...Array(cellCount)].map((_, i) => (
                activeCells.includes(i)
                ? <Item as={Foo} key={i} someAttr={123} />
                : <Item as={Bar} key={i} />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

I'm displaying either `<Foo />` or `<Bar />` in this loop. Now, I'd like to add `border-radius: 50%;` to both of them, using `styled-components`. I tried to do it with `as` attribute like above, but it doesn't work. It doesn't apply the class. I know I can add a separate style as `.something > * {border-radius: 50%;}`, but I want to avoid that.

How can I apply the same styles to different components?

Comment: "I tried to do it with `as` attribute like above, but it doesn't work. It doesn't apply the class." -- can you describe what exactly happens?

Comment: Nothing happens - the element don't get this auto-generated class that applies `border-radius: 50%`.

Comment: What version of styled-components are you using?

Comment: Newest version.

Comment: `as` prop should usually work but I suspect the root element of your `Foo` or `Bar` is not the regular HTML tag, but a custom component itself that doesn't take `className` prop. Is that the case?

Comment: Nope, their roots are `div`.